# Disable some Touchwiz features

Tags: samsung-touchwiz

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Music and the screen locks every time I make a call with the message "double tap to unlock". Can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the talkback feature if it's on.

Go to `Settings>Accessibility>Talkback` and uncheck.